# When to use forking or threading?

Tags: c, multithreading, multiprocessing, fork

I have the following problem statement:

> Implement a function substLinesMany ... . All the specified files should be processed concurrently. If any of the files result in an error, then substLinesMany will return false otherwise return true.

Would you use threading or forking here? (have to pick one)

Comment: If the function does what its name implies (changes lines in files), and the files live on the same filesystem, I would use neither.

Comment: Personally I would almost always choose to use threading over forking when there is information exchange involved.  Either way would work though.

Comment: @JS1 can threads return useful value though? I am trying to return 500 form this thread, and it just prints 0: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Hf10tgqR

Comment: @dgamma3 You passed a `NULL` as the second parameter to `pthread_join`. Read the docs.

Comment: `void *status; int err, val; err = pthread_join(tid, &status); val = (uintptr_t) status;`  The 500 you passed to `pthread_exit` is passed back to you as a void * if you use the 2nd argument to `pthread_join`.  But I have also done it another way where main passes pointers to each thread via the argument in `pthread_create` and each thread copies its data to the given pointer before exiting.

Comment: https://twitter.com/odinodin/status/530005490944970752 (I know, I know, it's an assignment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different opinion, just in case. Threading seems tempting due to the advantages mentioned by @CraigAnderson.

But don't forget the following facts:

1. Threading is very difficult. Shared memory means you'll have to protect critical code and data sections with locks, etc. It's a nightmare to debug.
2. Anecdotal evidence suggests that in most cases your parallel solution will be slower than the sequential one. The reason: cache misses. Memory is magnitudes slower than CPUs. If all your threads access all process memory all the time, all your CPUs will spend their time refreshing their cache.
3. The overhead of `fork` is much less than you think. Linux is copy-on-write, so the child process starts with the same physical memory pages as the parent. Only changed data will trigger writing new physical pages.
4. As you compare threading with forking, you implicitly assume a Unix OS. Threading is very useful on non-Unix systems (Windows), where process creation is a huge overhead.
5. Parallel programs need careful design, where each thread/process works on its own chunk of memory only, to minimize cache misses. So you'll find that using forking and some Unix stream IPC is very efficient, has minimum overhead and is much easier to debug.
6. The semantics of Unix IPC, especially pipes, provide an excellent and easy to use way to communicate between processes. For instance a `read` from a worker child's pipe blocks until results are available. Add a `select` loop in the parent and you have data exchange AND syncing with  a simple `read`.
7. Threading is less portable than forking. If you work on a multi-core embedded system with the uClibc library instead of glibc, well, uClibc has no threading.

References:

- http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=6364
- http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/ch07s03.html#id2923889
- http://web.stanford.edu/~ouster/cgi-bin/papers/threads.pdf
- http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000271.do The Perl Camel Book Threading chapter starts with 4 pages of warnings and discouragement
- https://brendaneich.com/2007/02/threads-suck/
- http://blog.codinghorror.com/threading-concurrency-and-the-most-powerful-psychokinetic-explosive-in-the-univ/

As you can see in the references, they are all big names: ESR, Ousterhout, Larry Wall, Brendan Eich, a StackOverflow founder. Magnitudes more intelligent than me, still scared stiff of threads.

Comment: I would like to see a reference for "95% of cases the parallel solution is slower than sequential".

Comment: Threading is difficult?! At lot of this answer is just speculation (not facts)

Comment: I looked at the first and third references - no evidence that "95% of cases your parallel solution is slower than the sequential one".  The second reference is to a book which is not available online.

Comment: Found this quote on Wikipedia - seems appropriate: "Anecdotal evidence is considered dubious support of a generalized claim".

Comment: Even if the anecdotal evidence comes from ESR, Ousterhout, Larry Wall, Brendan Eich et al. Dubious, for sure.

Comment: Most of your major concerns (points 1, 2, 5) apply to all parallel programs, not just threaded ones.  And honestly a lot of it sounds like FUD.  It may be true that parallelism isn't often the right answer to speed up a program.  But when it is the right answer, it doesn't have to be that difficult.  It depends on how much interactivity there is between your threads/processes.  But I will agree with you that it CAN get very difficult.

Answer (score 4):

I would use threading over forking.  Creating a new thread consumes fewer resources than creating a new process.  Threads share the same address space, while forking a process requires creating a new process with a new address space.  Given the nature of the function (substituting lines in a file), having a separate address space per file is not necessary.

The only drawback is that there likely is a a per-process limit on the number of simultaneous open files which might be hit while using threads.  That is a manageable problem though.